# Can $(y + z ) x_1 = (y_1 + z_1) x$ be an equation of a straight line in 3 dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Can we say,

$(y + z ) x_1 = (y_1 + z_1) x$ is also an equation of a straight line in $3$ dimensional space,

where $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x,y,z)$ are the coordinates of a given point and a variable point respectively on a 3D line that passes through the origin,

have seen equation of a straight line in $3$ dimensional space as,

$$(x-x_1 )/a = (y-y_1)/b = (z-z_1)/c$$

where $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is a known point in the line and $a$, $b$, $c$ are the direction ratios (drs) of the line,

I am trying to modify the equation into another form which one will look like the equation of a line in a 2D case like $ax + by + c = 0$,

My approach,

Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x,y,z)$ be the coordinates of any given and a variable point respectively on a 3D line that passes through the origin,

as direction ratios are just the length of the bases of the triangles formed in the space,
$$a = x_1, b = y_1 , c = z_1,$$

now, instead of working on direction ratios measured by the cosine functions, I am taking the $\tan$ functions and using $\tan \theta =$ opposite side/ base,

along the $y$ axis,

$$\tan \beta  = \frac{y_1}{x_1} = \frac yx,$$

along the $z$ axis,

$$\tan \gamma = \frac{z_1}{x_1} = \frac zx,$$

where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the angles made by the line with $y$ and $z$ axes respectively,

so,we are getting,
$$y = (\frac{y_1}{x_1}) x,$$

$$z = (\frac{z_1}{x_1}) x,$$

$$y + z = (\frac{y_1}{x_1}) x + (\frac{z_1}{x_1}) x$$

$$y + z = (y_1+ z_1) \frac {x}{x_1}$$

$$(y + z ) x_1 = (y_1 + z_1 ) x$$

which resembles the equation of a 2D line passing through the origin  $ax + by = 0$,

my approach is to simply the equation of a 3D line into simple linear equation of three variables,

also in books it is given $ax + by + cz + d  = 0$ is not the equation of a straight line but is the equation of a plane what I am finding is not the case as there a,b,c are not related to the plane but on the properties of a line what is perpendicular to the plane,

so I can conclude that $ax + by + cz + d  = 0$ will represent a straight line in space but with the above modification what I got as $(y + z ) x_1 = (y_1 + z_1 ) x$.

Just wanted to know if my approach is correct ?

thanks.

Comment: That is an equation of a plane $ax-by-bz=0, a=y_1+z_1, b=x_1$. The plane contains the origin. Any line in that plane will solve that equation.

Comment: i have just cross multiplied the terms in the equation of a line in (x-x1)/a = (y-y1)/b = (z-z1)/c , how can i get a plane from there ? as that will mean  (x-x1)/a = (y-y1)/b = (z-z1)/c was the equation of a plane, is my assumption correct ?

Comment: A line in space is represented by TWO linear equations. A single linear equation represents a plane.

Comment: Your supposed line contains points $(0,0,0)$, $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x1,y_1+k,z_1-k)$, where $k$ is any constant. Do you think those points are aligned?

Comment: "so I can conclude that $ax+by+cz+d=0$  will represent a straight line in space": your justification is unclear and... wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let us take $x_1=y_1=z_1=1$, so that your equation reads $$2x=y+z.$$

Now the three points $(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)$ and $(0, 1, -1)$ do satisfy the equation. But they are not aligned !

---

This proves that your equation is not that of a straight line. As is well-known, it is that of a plane.

Answer (score 0):

$(y+z)x_1=(y_1+z_1)x$ does not describe a line as for any value of $x$ we find $(y+z)x_1$ is constant,so the equation describes a line in the $zy$ plane for the given $x$-coordinate. Thus the equation $(y+z)x_1=(y_1+z_1)x$ describes a plane.

Comment: hope u meant for any value of x not z in   "does not describe a line as for any value of z
we find (y+z)x1 in ur post "(y+z)x1=(y1+z1)x"

Comment: moreover even though (y+ z) x1 is constant,for a given x, it does not accept any value of y and z but only defined values like y =2z,thereby confining it to a straight line.

Comment: @sachin >"thereby confining it to a straight line" - what is "it" referring to? You are forgetting that $x$ is arbitrary too. So even after fixing $x$, your locus is still a line. What do you think happens if we vary $x$?

Comment: @sachin Yes, apologies for the typo. However, as for each $x$-value there is a line in the $yz$-plane, over all $x$ values there is a continuum of lines (a plane).